# Mobile facebook login and Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a two-fold question in that it first asks a best practice for the situation, then asks how it should be implemented.

**The situation:** I'm creating a mobile app which operates through an API built in Rails. Meaning, users are created and fetched through the Rails API. The mobile app will allow the user to login via Facebook.

**Problem:** I'm not entirely familiar with how the Facebook login functions, such as what information should be used to fetch the database user.

**Question:** The goal is to login via Facebook in the mobile app and it fetch the user's data (or create the user) in the database via the API. So, should I set up the Facebook login on the mobile side? Or the website (API) side? And what information should be passed to/from the API?

I'm doing the same thing for Google+, but once I understand the best method for Facebook, I'm sure it will also apply to Google+ or any other oAuth authentication.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) with [OmniAuth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) strategies?

Comment: Yes, but is this would handle the facebook login on the API side instead of the mobile side. Is that method preferred? If so, what information would need to be passed back and forth between the API for the session to remain active in mobile?